# How to draw an UIImage or directly in -drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, drawrect

I have an `UIImage` which I want to draw on a `UIView`. But instead of creating an `UIImageView` and adding this as a subview, I want to overwrite `-drawRect:` and draw my UIView directly.

For example, my code looks like:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"foo.png"];

    // how to draw the directly into the view now?
}
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

Call `[img drawInRect:rect];`.

Comment: There is also `[img drawAtPoint:point]` too, although I prefer `drawInRect:`.

Comment: try to avoid this technique if you can; drawInRect and drawAtPoint have pretty terrible performance.

Comment: Thanks. I found these especially useful (combined with the similar NSString UIKit drawing add-ons) for views that contain background images & text and then added to scroll view. Drawing background image and text together in drawRect: avoids Quartz from blending the layers (as it would do if you used UIImageView & UILabel subviews approach) which has significant impact on scrolling performance

Answer (score 30):

BTW, you shouldn't load the image file in the drawRect method. Because the method is called whenever the view is required to update. Therefore, it (of course, loading procedure) may be called many many times during running.
(Furthermore, OS2.x's imageNamed method has a bug -- not cached the image and leaked it.)

Therefore, you'd better to load the file in the initialization method, not in the drawRect.

Comment: Thanks for that helpful information. Unfortunately, which "initialization" method do you mean?

Comment: He probably means `+(void)initialize`, or the usual `init` method, depending on what you're doing.