# Customizing Custom UIView class

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiview, custom-component

I have a custom UIView class that creates a view I can use in my main view controller that allows for better dragging.  The problem, is that right now, the object I'm dragging is just a black box.  I would like to be able to put my own custom image into that box.  How would I do this? The custom UIView only has a .h and a .m and I don't know which method to put the code in.

Here's the code Im using right now

```
UIImageView *player = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 37, 37)];
player.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ghost.png"];
[self addSubview: player];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could

- Add your custom view in your view controllers main xib file and add the image view to it in the interface builder view
- In your view controllers `viewDidLoad` method you could add the `UIImageView` to the custom view using your current code
- Override the `drawRect` method of your custom view and draw the image there see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1663815/how-to-draw-an-uiimage-or-directly-in-drawrect) (however note the answer which says you should not load the image in the `drawRect` method, load the image on construction of your view in the `initWithFrame` or the `awakeFromNib` method depending on how you load it)